# How to convert a string value to int so that it does not skip the preceding 0?

Tags: c#

I have this value in a string

```
string FinalValue=" 0XXXXXXXXX";
```

which i need to fetch in integer value.

But when i convert it like below

```
 custNUmber = int.Parse(FinalValue);
```

it says value was either too large or too small for an int32. c#

and when i use long it skips the first digit 0.

Comment: A leading zero has no significance in a number. If it does have significance for you, you're not dealing with numbers, you're dealing with strings that happen to contain digits.

Comment: yes it matters for me if i am to make a metch in databse for phone number..and i get it in string format through some api..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet I'd say you are from britain. Is it your mobile?

Comment: Then you should store it as a string, not as a number.

Comment: Phone numbers are definitely string data, they just happen to contain (mainly) digits. If you try to treat them as numbers, you're bound to have problems - like the one you've described.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet how would you store the phone number (+49)241/169-375-728 in your database? Let me guess: you round it to -1033... ;)

Comment: Do you want remove spaces from begin and end? Maybe you want to save telephone string as FinalValue.trim()?

Comment: Alex K: so that i can query in database and can know if number exist.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - it's not as simple as you think - given a plethora of different ways to write a phone number; omitting or not country/area codes, etc. that's not something easily done, especially if you want to support international numbers. You may try to strip all characters but digits for comparison alone, but even then I'd expect some issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maths says that `07894204661 == 7894204661` that's why resulting `long` is always *7894204661*; if you want to *restore leading zeros* when converting `long` back to `String` (e.g. in order to show it in a TextBox, print out to Console etc.) you can use *formatting*:

```
  String FinalValue=" 07894204661";
  long custNUmber = long.Parse(FinalValue.Trim());

  // 11 digits wanted; "07894204661" is the outcome
  String value = custNUmber.ToString("D11");
```

P.S. `int.MaxValue == 2147483647` only; that is the *cause of the exception* when you try to convert "07894204661" into `int`.

Answer (score 2):

A leading zero is not part of an integer at all. Actually `0123==123` yields true.

So you could convert it to long first to handle the case that it's a numeric value that is simply to large (f.e. for logging purposes):

```
int custNUmber;
long l;
if(long.TryParse(FinalValue, out l))
{
    if(l < int.MinValue || l > int.MaxValue)
    {
        // log
    }
    else
    {
        custNUmber = (int)l;
    }
}
else
{
    // not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using long is the right thing to do.  The zero isn't part of the number so it's supposed to skip it.  I'd worry about the leading space.  You might need to trim that off before parsing it.

```
custNUmber = long.Parse(FinalValue.trim());
```

Comment: You need to give details of why you think not.